# Javascript - how to load the same JSON (or alternative) file into both node.js and browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, browser

I'm looking to load into memory a JSON file (or a .js file with an object in it) into both a node script and into the browser. Is there any clean and pure JS way to do this without having a separate file for each?

The file simply holds properties about things that are used on both client and server side, the goal is when I need to change some property it will reflect on both the client (javascript) and the server (node). The does not need to be updated while running, and ideally should be loaded and cached on page load and script start respectively.

I've tried using a .json file which made it easy to require in node, but in the browser the only solutions I saw used packages or some sort of over complicated api that seemed too overkill for my use (although this might be my only option). If i store the properties as a .js file with an object defined in it it's easy to load in browser, but not in node without module.exprots.

Seems inconvenient that I can't easily do this, especially when it's a just a small JSON object with item properties.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi, in nodejs you can directly `require` file and in browser use a get `request` to get the same file would work best i'm guessing. If you have a websocket connection between your node server and browser you can send it through could be a second option

Comment: @HalilÇakar I do in fact have a web socket connection running. I may actually just send it through websockets to preserve maximum compatibility as I was under the impression that the fetch api wasn't 100% supported until fairly recently. In an ideal world there would be some way to structure my file such that I could one-line import it into both the browser and node (without fetch, even if that's what the browser does under the hood).

Comment: Yea an ideal world but for now it's not working this way so sending through websocket is the best choice for you i'm guessing, since your node is gonna work anyway :)

Comment: Hmm do you have a webpack or parcel project? In case you can actually import json in :D

Comment: @HalilÇakar my websocket connection is actually pretty critical in my application so I'm going to wait and see if any other solution pops up yet since sending it through the websocket will create some blocking for other clients since stringifying it is synchronous.

Comment: @HalilÇakar I do not, I have no other need to package anything else yet so it seems overkill, although I recognize that would make my life a lot simpler. It's frustrating browsers don't support module.exports. I understand why it isn't, but some how making it available browser side could help out a small group of people like myself.

Comment: Seems to me the solution is `require` for server, exposing the file via `express.static` to be `fetch`ed by browser, if you don't want Webpack. `fetch` has excellent support now, if you're sill not sure then just add a polyfill then you're 100% safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the file public, and use it in front and backend.

Asuming you use epxress.

```js
app.use(express.static('./')); //Use static folder
```

But note sharing files can be inscure if you have senstive information, but you already know that.

#### Edit

You say it is not the problem, in the comments. I say then you have to make some sort of endpoint to export this array. Do this:

```js
const object = {
   // You object here
}

app.get('/route', (req, res) => {
   res.json(object);
}
```

Client:

```js
fetch('/route').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    // You have access to the data, here.
})
```

Like this you can use the object on both the backend and frontend.

Altough I suspect there is a way to do this using also static folder.

Comment: This is not the problem in question... the "use it in front and backend" is.

Comment: @Ralph receck if the answer meets you needs. I have edited.

Comment: This is sufficient and what I ended up doing. Would be nice if I was able to fetch synchronously. I made it work as is but really I wanted the file to be cached at the beginning and then let the rest of the script run (on both client/server), as opposed to having to have it load asynchronously then start calling everything else that is synchronous.